# How can I find a file within any description of path?

Tags: c#, file, path-finding

I need find the specific file/folder on my hard drive. 
For example i need find a file (do1.bat) and then store the path of the file. But i dont know where can it be stored, so i have to scan all hard drive.
How can i use C# for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be

```
var results = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\", "do1.bat", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This would recurse through all directory and collect all files named `do1.bat`. Unfortunatly this will **not work on complete `c:\`** since it will throw **exceptions** if you don't have access to a directory, which surely will happen.

So this is a recursive version:

```
private static void FindFile(DirectoryInfo currentDirectory, string pattern, List<FileInfo> results)
{
    try 
    {
        results.AddRange(currentDirectory.GetFiles(pattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in currentDirectory.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(d => d.Name != "." && d.Name != ".."))
            FindFile(dir, pattern, results);
    }
    catch
    { 
        // probably no access to directory
    }
}
```

This recurses through the directory tree and *tries* to get the files in a directory and then all subdirectories (except `.` and `..`).
You can use it this way:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\");
List<FileInfo> results = new List<FileInfo>();
FindFile(d, "do1.bat", results);
```

This will find all files named `do1.bat` in any subdirectory of `C:\\` and enlist the `FileInfo`s in the `results` list.

Answer (score 1):

this should provide you a list of files, matching your search pattern

```
string[] Result = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "do1.bat", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: This will surely fail because there are directories you don't have access to and `GetFiles` will throw an exception for those and not continue for the other directories.

Comment: yes, this approach requires reading access to all subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    List<string> lstfilepaths = new List<string>();
    public static void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory) 
    {
      // Process the list of files found in the directory.

       string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);

       foreach(string fileName in fileEntries) // included as per your logic
       {
            if(fileName == "do1.bat")
              {
                 ProcessFile(fileName);
              }
       }

    // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
        string [] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
        foreach(string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
             ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);
     }

     public static void ProcessFile(string path) 
       {
        lstfilepaths.Add(path);    
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

For one file:

```
public string FindFileByName(string fileName, string searchPath)
{
    string resultPath = null;
    DirectoryInfo directoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(searchPath);

    FileInfo foundFile = directoryInWhichToSearch.GetFiles(fileName, SearchOption.AllDirectories)[0];

    resultPath = foundFile.FullName;

    return resultPath;
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
string fileFullPath = FindFileByName("do1.bat", @"C:\");
```